# alternative for kendo treeview and HierarchicalDataSource

Tags: kendo-ui, requirejs

For some reason i have problem in my ENV to load read transport for HierarchicalDataSource and load in Treeview with error :

```
kendo.web.js:6681 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
```

and its not kendo problem, maybe some scripts override some functions and fuctionName is undefined.

Any way this is not going to work in ENV: Kendo UI v2015.2.624+jQuery JavaScript Library v1.11.0 +RequireJS 2.1.11+kendo.dataviz

My Q is is there some alternative for this bcs we need treeview for datagram showing tree of inherent classes and objects, or i need to look some other library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you've given up on trying to solve the problem you have with the Kendo TreeView, so I won't try to figure out what's wrong with it.

There are many TreeView components out there. You can take a look at the ones listed on [this page](http://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/146/top-5-best-tree-view-jquery-and-javascript-plugins).

The page contains descriptions, screenshots and links to the homepages and github links for 7 such components: [jQueryFileTree](http://jqueryfiletree.github.io/), [Bootstrap TreeView](http://jonmiles.github.io/bootstrap-treeview/), [jqTree](http://mbraak.github.io/jqTree/), [jsTree](https://www.jstree.com/demo/), [FancyTree](http://wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/demo/), [jQuery bonsai](http://simonwade.me/jquery-bonsai) and [Treed](http://jaredforsyth.com/treed/).

Comment: ok, tnx, maybe best to try is Treed, i will try it but this is it, i think maybe alternative more in kendo similar, but js will work .